# Lighted medicine cabinet needs GFCI outlet and Dimmer - why?

Tags: electrical, lighting, light-fixture

I'm having my GC prepare electrical for lighted medicine cabinet and I'm trying to understand the wiring instructions so I can make sure he does the work right before the walls go up. My confusion is why this lighted medicine cabinet requires BOTH a connection to a GFCI outlet AND a connection to a dimmer.

Is the dimmer switch here the same as any other dimmer switch that I'd use for a normal recessed light, which turns on and off and also controls brightness level? If yes, then why do I need to connect to a GFCI outlet at all?

If it isn't a normal dimmer switch for a recessed light, then what type of dimmer is it and where do i find one?

Thanks for your help in advance!
[image: Wiring diagram for dimmer]
[image]

Comment: Is the item UL listed (or listed with a similar listing agency?) CE is not a listing agency.

Comment: Note that the drawing doesn't actually show a GFCI *outlet*, but a blank-face GFCI - because an outlet near a sink must be GFCI protected and the outlet built onto the cabinet is just a plain outlet. So if you already have a GFCI outlet next to your sink then you can wire into the load side of that, otherwise you need to add a GFCI like that blank face one in the drawing.

Answer (score 2):

The GFCI is purely for the outlets (as required by code for outlets near sinks).

The light is separate and controlled by the dimmer. You can also use a normal lightswitch.

The reason for having both is that you want outlets to be powered even when the light is off. To be able to charge your electric toothbrush while you are not using it for example. Dimming outlets is not a good idea in general.

Comment: And the reverse is true too - you don't want a GFCI trip on the outlet to turn out the lights.